# Confused about what comes after Chrome Apps

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, progressive-web-apps

I have a question regarding Google Chrome apps. We are developing software that has previously accessed the serial port through a Chrome app. As Google will stop supporting Chrome Apps, we now have a problem.

If I understood correctly, then the chrome-apps can only be used on a chromebook after the end of support?

Will google end the support for the "hosted apps" and "packaged apps"?

If the created manifest contains the following part („app“:{…}), is it always an app? 
[Picture of the place in the source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Y6V.jpg)

But this is displayed in the browser under "chrome: // apps" and under "chrome: // extensions". Is the app still usable after the end of the support?

Also, we have read of Progressive Web Apps as a replacement, but is it also possible to access the serial port? Are they as powerful as the Chrome apps?


many thanks for answers :)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217146/chrome-extension-how-to-use-serial-port-now-that-apps-are-sunsetting/44877138 and there is a relevant crbug you may want to check out: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=654590

Comment: thank you very much for the comment. Can you also tell me if google quits the "hosted apps" and "packaged apps"?