# General Serial Interface library for Chrome JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, serial-port

Does there exist a general Serial Interface to allow javascript in Chrome to access a local serial port?

Preferably, I'd like to be able to do something along the lines of

```
var serial = new serialPort(3,9600,noParity,8,oneStopBit);
serial.write("Testing...")
var response = serial.read(1000);
```

in JavaScript. I don't mind that the end-user needs to install a Chrome Extension or somehow give permission ahead of time before I am allowed access.

I have read online something about node.js but can't figure out how to implement it. Any advice would be welcome...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension: how to use serial port (now that apps are sunsetting)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217146/chrome-extension-how-to-use-serial-port-now-that-apps-are-sunsetting)